# How to know which triggers/classes are running when a new user is created?

Tags: trigger, user, debugging

I don't know which triggers run when a new user is created, so I don't know how to modify the Debug Logs criteria to show me the information I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your profile is  **system administrator**  then In debug log > Traced Entity Name should be Your name.